# JQuery always returning first option when looking for selected item in select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following select:

```
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="-1">All</option>
  <option value="7">Red</option>
  <option value="8">Green</option>
  <option value="9">Blue</option>
</select>
```

I then have a function that runs to see what the selected option is in the select:

```
function getSelectedOption () {

  var selection = $('.my-select').val();

  console.log(selection);

}
```

This is where it gets weird, I can run that function when 'Red', 'Green' and 'Blue' is selected and it'll always return me the correct value. But when I select 'All', the correct value is returned (-1), but when I go back and select 'Red' or any other option after that, the returned value is always (-1). Suggesting that 'All' is selected. When it's not. I also inspected the DOM to see, and in the case where 'Red' was selected, the DOM looks like:

```
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="-1">All</option>
  <option value="7" selected="selected">Red</option>
  <option value="8">Green</option>
  <option value="9">Blue</option>
</select>
```

But `$('.my-select').val()` is returning me the wrong value.

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When do you invoke that function ?

Comment: By the way, __val__ is not __`value`__

Comment: A bizarre but possible cause would be that you have more than one select with the same class `my-select`. Also as Rayon said the exact moment when you call the function is vital.

Comment: Here you go — https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2atcye1w/

Comment: ^^ doesnt solve the OP issue. Moreover it has deprecated style of binding events, Please refrain from suggesting deprecated syntax.

Comment: @Reddy — What ? What is the issue by the way ? Could you reproduce it ? I failed :(

Comment: @Rayon then what was the purpose of that fiddle?

Comment: $('.my-select').val() will work if the html is correct and there is only one select with class my-select. Use an ID to access the specific select directly

Comment: Where are you calling getSelectedOption? Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Comment: @Reddy — Event registration approached used in the fiddle is just for the sake of demonstration. I doubt that will somehow impact the example I have shared, I never suggested anyone to go with that approach. To answer your question about Fiddle, it is to convey that if OP has used valid `value` attribute, rest of the code should work! I did search for solution from your end as you were concerned about what _solves the OP issue_ but I failed to find one!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.my-select').find('option:selected').val()
```

and it should not be `<option val="7"></option>`, instead it should look like this:

```
 <option value="7"></option>
```

Comment: $('.my-select').val() will work if the html is correct

Comment: I've fixed my html that it says 'value' instead of 'val' . That was just a typo typing out the question. Also, your way does not work. Sorry

Comment: @DeanGibson it would if your html and explanation was correct. Now please go back and show us how you call the function and tell us if there are more than one "my-select" or perhaps a typo or a console error

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work as it should, what browser are you using?

```js
var $select = $('select');

$select.on('change', function (event) {
  console.log($(event.target).val());
});

$select.trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="-1">All</option>
  <option value="7">Red</option>
  <option value="8" selected>Green</option>
  <option value="9">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please make a note that you fixed his invalid html

Comment: why you have not use `this` instead of `event.target` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong attribute in option is `val`, correct attribute is `value` for assign different value then text/label

```js
function getSelectedOption () {

  var selection = $('.my-select').val();

  console.log(selection);

}

$(".my-select").change(getSelectedOption);

getSelectedOption();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="my-select">
  <option value="-1">All</option>
  <option value="7" selected="selected" >Red</option>
  <option value="8">Green</option>
  <option value="9">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: val=... is not correct. That would be needing find and attr